# When will this algorithm repeat itself?

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I was messing around with different ways of manipulating strings of even length in Java when I came across the following algorithm.

Given a string, rearrange it as follows: first character, last character, second character, second to last character, etc etc. So for example, the string "test" would yield "ttes", which would yield "tste", which would yield "test" again.

I started trying out longer strings, assuming that the number of iterations that it would take for each string to "cycle around" would be equal to its length, as was the case with the "test" string. However, this is not the case. Each string of even length that was tested took a seemingly random number of iterations before cycling back around. Here's a short table of the first few values of the number of iterations for a given string length:

[Table showing values for the described algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djty3.png)

As you can see just from the first few values, there's really no easily findable pattern which can predict the number of iterations it will take for the random string to cycle around. The value seems to kind of just jump all over the place. So my question is, can anyone explain why the number of iterations behaves like it does? Is there any way to predict what the number of iterations needed for a string of a given length will be?

To try to answer this, I wrote a short program in Java to brute-force calculate the number of iterations needed, hoping to find a pattern through more trials. I didn't have any luck with it, but if it'll help, here's the code (sorry about the sloppiness):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class mainClass
{
    //initialize global variables
    static String originalString = "";
    static Random randGen = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());


    //main method
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //add two new random characters to the original string
        originalString += Character.toString((char)(randGen.nextInt(99) + 32));
        originalString += Character.toString((char)(randGen.nextInt(99) + 32));

        //show the length of the string
        System.out.print(originalString.length() + "\t");

        //"decode" the string once to get it going and initialize count
        String test = decode(originalString);
        int count = 1;

        //"decode" the string until it is equal to the original string again
        while(!test.equals(originalString))
        {
            test = decode(test);
            count++;
        }

        //print out the number of iterations needed to "cycle around"
        System.out.println(count);

        //restart
        main(null);
    }

    public static String decode(String str)
    {
        //initialize result variable
        String result = "";

        //perform the rearranging process
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length() / 2; i ++)
        {
            result += Character.toString(str.charAt(i));
            result += Character.toString(str.charAt(str.length() - 1 - i));
        }

        //return the result
        return result;
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Perhaps the question should be focused on the code, and how to best model or compute the cycle. Using random `chars` which may have many duplicates in large arrays seems like a bad idea at least to me.

Comment: @Andreas He's asking for the running time of the algorithm -- that kind of question shows up here all the time.

Comment: @Linus I thought that that might be an issue as well, so I ran the program two separate times for strings up to 1000 characters in length and compared the number of iterations needed to "cycle around" each string. In both cases they were identical, even though different seeds were used.

Comment: `cycle` has been mentioned - every _permutation_ can be broken into them. How many applications of a permutation containing cycles of length 2 and 3 (and nothing longer) yield the original order?

Comment: @Deskarano  Thanks for checking, it is probably not an issue. A version could be designed for `int[]` consisting of unique consecutive numbers (e.g. 0,1,2,...,n) but I doubt it would shed new light on the matter. The cycle length would still be seemingly erratic.

Comment: @Linus I did as you suggested, and plotted the result. Interesting patterns.

Answer (score 1):

To brute-force calculate the number of iterations needed to return to the original sequence, you can instead start with a sequence of unique numbers, e.g. 0,1,2,3,4,...,N, and apply the function repeatedly until you're back to that original sequence.

There is no randomness that could potentially skew the result, and it doesn't require any potential proof that if one value returns to it's original position, all other values would have too. It is also much faster than String concatenation.

This code does this. It can do it on odd length sequences too.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int len = 1; len <= 1000; len++) {
        int count = 0;
        short[] value = build(len);
        do {
            value = apply(value);
            count++;
        } while (! done(value));
        System.out.printf("%d\t%d%n", len, count);
    }
}
private static short[] build(int len) {
    short[] value = new short[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        value[i] = (short)i;
    return value;
}
private static boolean done(short[] value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
        if (value[i] != i)
            return false;
    return true;
}
private static short[] apply(short[] input) {
    short[] output = new short[input.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
        output[i] = input[(i & 1) == 0 ? i / 2 : input.length - i / 2 - 1];
    return output;
}
```

If you plot the result, you get this:

[image: Plot]

As you can see, the results are pretty scattered, but there are some patterns.

I'm not a numbers wizard, but this seems somewhat similar to the "randomness" of prime numbers, for which there are many number theories.

This is why I had suggested asking this question on https://math.stackexchange.com/, where the true math wizards hang out. Maybe they can provide more insight.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll post this to [http://math.stackexchange.com/](http://math.stackexchange.com/) too, see if anyone over there has any insights as well.

Answer (score 0):

The first character will always remain in the same spot.
It is sufficient to keep track of the position of the second element in the list.
It will never iterate more than n-1 times as the change in position should cycle through back to its original position, and each character will move from position to position in a cycle due to the algorithm. for n=10:

```
a b c d e f g h i j
a j b i c h d g e f
a f j e b g i d c h
a h f c j d e i b g
a g h b f i c e j d
a d g j h e b c f i
a i d f g c j b h e
a e i h d b f j g c
a c e g i j h f d b
a b c d e f g h i j

cycle pattern:
1 2 4 8 3 6 7 5 9 1
```

So regardless of the position flow, it will cycle back in at most n-1 moves.

In some cases, the cycles are shorter:

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p
a p b o c n d m e l f k g j h i
a i p h b j o g c k n f d l m e
a e i m p l h d b f j n o k g c
a c e g i k m o p n l j h f d b
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p

1  2 4  8 15 1
3  6 12 7 14 3
5 10  11 9 13 5
```

(as an aside, this is similar to a^x(mod m)=y, which depends on whether x and m are relatively prime to each other.  In that case, if they are relatively prime, it will cycle through all the numbers.)

However, in our case, the sequence is not clearcut, but you can simplify by looking at the character starting in position 1:

```
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 1
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 2
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 4
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 8
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 16
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 11
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1] 21
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 1
```

As long as swapping continues for 19 iterations before it hits the n/2+1 position (11, in this case) then it will take 21 iterations.  If it returns back in less, then that's how long the entire array will take.

So you can determine the number of times it needs to decode from looking at position 1 and moving it according to the swapping algorithm (but only applying it where the '1' appears).  It will take O(n) to check (at most n-1 moves), and save you the trouble from swapping the entire array.